# How to apply Zend ACL with neo4j database

Tags: php, neo4j, zend-framework2, authorization, acl

I have developed a project using zend and neo4j db. Till now I haven't used sessions now I have requirement of applying authorization to various types of users. I don't know whether Zend Acl can be directly implemented with neo4j. If any one used ACL with neo4j and can provide some examples then I would be very grateful to that person. On searching I came up with this link..

[Graph Acl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graph-acl)

Is it helpful ?

Answer (score 0):

There are no built-in ZendAcl Neo4j backed plugins. Note that ZendAcl does not have any built-in persistence features at the core.

You'll need to write an ACL plugin that will then create the necessary Cypher queries.

An example with Doctrine : https://monzee.wordpress.com/2009/06/14/developing-a-doctrine-backed-acl-helper-tdd-style-part-1/

Comment: Thanks for your efforts....one more thing the link which I have provided in question description is it helpful ? Can I implement it directly ?